# The limit of $x\frac{a^x\log{a}+b^x\log{b}}{a^x+b^x}-\log{(a^x+b^x)}$

Tags: calculus, limits

> Show that
>   $$\lim_{x\to\infty}x\frac{a^x\log{a}+b^x\log{b}}{a^x+b^x}-\log{(a^x+b^x)}=0$$ where $a,b>0$.

I have tried L'Hôpital's rule, but makes the function more complicated.
Since $a^x+b^x$ grows faster than $a^x$ and $b^x$, maybe there is some inequality fitting this problem?

What if

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}x\frac{\sum_{i=1}^na_i^x\log{a_i}}{\sum_{i=1}^na_i^x}-\log{(\sum_{i=1}^na_i^x)}$$

Comment: This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: But please don't close the problem; it is a nice exercise to answer it.

Comment: @T.Bongers thank you, I will improve my question

Answer (score 2):

If $a=b$, then $L=x\,\frac{a^x\log(a)+b^x\log(b)}{a^x+b^x}-\log(a^x+b^x)=-\log(2)$ and therefore, we have $\lim_{x\to \infty}(-\log(2))=-\log(2)$.

We now examine the case for which $a\ne b$.  Without Loss of Generality, we may assume that $a>b$.  We can write the term of interest as

$$\begin{align}
L&=x\,\frac{a^x\log(a)+b^x\log(b)}{a^x+b^x}-\log(a^x+b^x)\\\\
&=\frac{a^x\log(a^x)+b^x\log(b^x)-(a^x+b^x)\log(a^x+b^x)}{a^x+b^x}\\\\
&=\frac{(b/a)^x\log((b/a)^x)-\log(1+(b/a)^x)-(b/a)^x\log(1+(b/a)^x)}{1+(b/a)^x} \tag 1
\end{align}$$

Since all of the terms in the numerator approach zero as $x\to \infty$ while the denominator approaches $1$, we have

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}L=0$$

for $a\ne b$.

Answer (score 0):

First step: Try a special case.

Setting $a = b$ gives that the entire expression breaks down to $x\log a  - \log(2a^x) = x\log a - \log(2) - x\log a = -\log(2) \neq 0$,
so in general the limit is not zero.

However, if $a < b$ then we see that we can try to get some estimates for how things will grow since, heuristically, $b^x$ trumps $a^x$ in growth.

We see that $$\log(a^x + b^x) - \log(b^x) = \log((a/b)^x + 1)\to \log(1) = 0,$$ since $0 < a/b < 1$. So, we can replace the above difference by 
$$x\left(\frac{a^x\log a + b^x \log b}{a^x + b^x}\right) - x\log(b).$$

This leads to the following computation by putting the $x's$ together and continuing to consolidate and factoring:
$$x\left(\frac{a^x\log a + b^x \log b}{a^x + b^x}\right) - x\log(b) = x\left(\frac{(a/b)^x\log a + \log b}{(a/b)^x + 1} - \log(b)\right) = x\left(\frac{(a/b)^x\log a - (a/b)^x\log b}{(a/b)^x + 1}\right) = x(a/b)^x\left(\frac{\log a - \log b}{(a/b)^x + 1}\right).$$

Now, we see that since $0 < a/b < 1$ that $a(a/b)^x \to 0$ but the other factor converges to $\log(a) - \log(b)$, which is finite. So the entire limit is zero.

Note the continual use of $a$ being strictly less than $b$ in this entire case.